# Remove all rows between two sentinel strings in a column using pandas (but not the sentinel strings)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

given a big dataframe, how can I remove all the things between two specific strings, here "start" and "end". Yesteday, I asked a similar question but removing the two strings (I post my solution here below). Now I would like to see how I can keep also the strings. I have been trying to get the next row using itertuples, but I still haven't figured out how to do it.

`df1`:

```
   c1     c2
0   1      1
1   2  start
2   3      3
3   4    end
4   5      5
5   6  start
6   7    end
7   8      0
```

code to remove strings and things in between:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'c1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
     'c2': ['1', 'start', '3', 'end',
            '5', 'start', 'end', 0]})

df2 = copy.copy(df)
flag = False
list_a = []



for j in df.itertuples():
    if j.c2 == 'start':
        flag = True
        list_a.append((j))
    elif j.c2 =='end':
        flag = False
        list_a.append((j))
    elif flag:
        list_a.append((j))

list_a = tuple(list_a) 
to_remove_df = pd.DataFrame(list_a, columns=['index','c1','c2'])
to_remove_df = to_remove_df["c2"]
removed_df = pd.merge(df, to_remove_df, on=["c2"], how="outer", indicator=True).query('_merge != "both"').drop('_merge', 1)
```

output `df2`:

```
   c1 c2
0   1  1
4   5  5
7   8  0
```

Wanted output:
`df1`:

```
   c1     c2
0   1      1
1   2  start
3   4    end
4   5      5
5   6  start
6   7    end
7   8      0
```

Comment: Ciao Giorgio, which one should be the output in case of start, 2,3,start,end?

Comment: Ciao :) it should stay the same. It should be always between the closest start and end. So also if it was "start, 2,3,start,1,end", the result should be " start, 2,3,start,end". Just to be clear though: in my dataframe this cannot happen, after start there is always end.

Comment: is there always a start before end and an end after start, without duplicates? (i.e. not end-start-start-end-start)

Comment: From the data I look at so far, it's alway start-end-start-end. No duplicates, no missing starts or ends.

Comment: Then you should really not loop and use a [vectorial solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70788820/16343464) ;)

Comment: @mozway my solution too is vectorial. Furthermore produce the expected output ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to *not* add the indeces from the start and stop location to `a`.

Change this:

```
for j in df.itertuples():
    if j.c2 == 'start':
        flag = True
        list_a.append((j))
    elif j.c2 =='end':
        flag = False
        list_a.append((j))
    elif flag:
        list_a.append((j))
```

to this:

```
for j in df.itertuples():
    if j.c2 == 'start':
        flag = True
    elif j.c2 =='end':
        flag = False
    elif flag:
        list_a.append((j))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is always a logical succession of "start" and "end" (i.e. start first, end after, no duplicate in between). You can simply take the odd chunks delimited by start/end to build a mask:

```
mask = df['c2'].isin(['start', 'end']).cumsum().mod(2).astype(bool)
```

Then use the mask to slice:

Bounds included:

```
df[~(mask & mask.shift())]
```

Output:

```
   c1     c2
0   1      1
1   2  start
3   4    end
4   5      5
5   6  start
6   7    end
7   8      0
```

Bounds excluded:

```
df[~(mask | mask.shift())]
```

output:

```
   c1 c2
0   1  1
4   5  5
7   8  0
```

Comment: The `mod(2)` is clever, but relies on every 'start' tag being followed by exactly one and only one 'end' tag, else it will break.

Comment: @smci hence my initial disclaimer ;) This seems the most reasonable however

Comment: @mozway this looks great, only two questions. what if for example there is an "end" before a start? and how could it work if "start" and "end" where on 2 different columns?

Comment: 1- then you need to invert the mask. In needed, you can programmatically determine what is the first value. 2- simply select start and end independently, then add them before the `cumsum`

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible vectorial solution which should be easy to understand.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'c1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
     'c2': ['1', 'start', '3', 'end',
            '5', 'start', 'end', 0]})
```

Now I want to mark the sequences containing *start* and *end*. In order to do so I first assign 1 where there is a *start* and 0 where there is a *end*. Then I forward fill the `nan`

```py
diz = {"start": 1, "end": 0}
df["mask"] = df["c2"].map(diz).ffill()
```

Where the output is

```sh
   c1     c2  mask
0   1      1   NaN
1   2  start   1.0
2   3      3   1.0
3   4    end   0.0
4   5      5   0.0
5   6  start   1.0
6   7    end   0.0
7   8      0   0.0
```

After that I set 1 where there is a *end* and I do not modify otherwise and fill `nan` with 0s.

```py
df["mask"] = np.where(df["c2"].eq("end"), 1, df["mask"])
df["mask"] = df["mask"].fillna(0)
```

Here the output is

```sh
   c1     c2  mask
0   1      1   0.0
1   2  start   1.0
2   3      3   1.0
3   4    end   1.0
4   5      5   0.0
5   6  start   1.0
6   7    end   1.0
7   8      0   0.0
```

Next I want to remove all elements where `mask` is 1 and `c2` is not *start* or *end*.

```py
df["to_remove"] = df["mask"].eq(1) &  ~df["c2"].isin(['start', 'end'])
```

Here the output is

```sh
   c1     c2  mask  to_remove
0   1      1   0.0      False
1   2  start   1.0      False
2   3      3   1.0       True
3   4    end   1.0      False
4   5      5   0.0      False
5   6  start   1.0      False
6   7    end   1.0      False
7   8      0   0.0      False
```

Finally I remove all to_remove `True` and remove the columns we added on the way

```py
df = df[df["to_remove"].ne(True)]\
    .drop(columns=["mask", "to_remove"])
```

And you have your expected output

```sh
   c1     c2
0   1      1
1   2  start
3   4    end
4   5      5
5   6  start
6   7    end
7   8      0
```